# How do I find gaps in my array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  If I have an ordered array of numbers, say

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

How do I find the numerical elements that aren't present in my array, between the smallest and greatest values in the array?  For instance in the above, the missing values are

```
[3, 5, 6]
```

If my array were

```
[2, 7]
```

the missing values I'd be looking for would be

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the existing numbers from the expected range of numbers:

```
(numbers.first..numbers.last).to_a - numbers
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer complicated solutions:

```
[1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9].chunk_while { |a, b| a + 1 == b }
                  .each_cons(2)
                  .flat_map { |x, y| (x.last + 1).upto(y.first - 1).to_a }
#=> [3, 5, 6]
```